# How to add serial number column in magento sales report grid

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have to show Sr.No column in magento sales report grid

Now my report grid is like

[image]

I have to show Sr.No depend on PO.No like below(PO number showing 4 times means it have 4 product in that order)

Please let me know how to do this?
[image]